# sscanf_s can't find all values from string

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, format, scanf

I want to parse integers from a string of text that looks like:

```
"f 1/2/3 4/5/6 7/8/9"
```

into:

```
int arr1[3] = { 1, 4, 7 };
int arr2[3] = { 2, 5, 8 };
int arr3[3] = { 3, 6, 9 };
```

I wrote the following code to use `sscanf_s` to parse according to the general format of the strings:

```
// line = "f 1/2/3 4/5/6 7/8/9"
int arr1[3], arr2[3], arr3[3];

sscanf_s(line.c_str(), "f %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d",
    &arr1[0], &arr2[0], &arr3[0],
    &arr1[1], &arr2[1], &arr3[1],
    &arr1[2], &arr2[2], &arr3[2]);
```

Strangely, the contents of my arrays after running this code are:

```
arr1 = { 4, 7, -858993460 };
arr2 = { 5, 8, -858993460 };
arr3 = { 6, 9, -858993460 };
```

This is a kind of strange result, it's almost like it loads in the data correctly but then shifts the arrays to the left by one. Strangely, `sscanf_s` returns `9`, which indicates that it found 9 matches using the format I passed in. I have been trying to find an error but I really do not see what the code is doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just compiled this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int arr1[3], arr2[3], arr3[3];

int main()
{
    std::string line = "f 1/2/3 4/5/6 7/8/9";
    sscanf_s(line.c_str(), "f %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d",
        &arr1[0], &arr2[0], &arr3[0],
        &arr1[1], &arr2[1], &arr3[1],
        &arr1[2], &arr2[2], &arr3[2]);

    std::cout << "arr1 : " << arr1[0] << ", " << arr1[1] << ", " << arr1[2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "arr2 : " << arr2[0] << ", " << arr2[1] << ", " << arr2[2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "arr3 : " << arr3[0] << ", " << arr3[1] << ", " << arr3[2] << std::endl;
}
```

And it works fine.

Comment: I rebuilt the entire VS solution and it seems to be working fine now... Really have no idea why it wasn't running correctly before. Thanks for your reply, though.